# Is it possible to name individual tokens in a production in ANTLR4?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

Let's say I want to parse a single point with ANTLR4:

```
grammar Point;
point : '(' INT ',' INT ')';
INT : [0-9]+;
```

It'd be nice if I could name the first INT to `x` and the second to `y`. Is there any way to name them, so I could access them more gracefully in code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use labels:

```
point : '(' x=INT ',' y=INT ')';
```

This works reasonably well with tokens, but for parser rules labels may not be set if an exception is thrown during parsing. In other words, avoid the following:

```
point
  : '('
    x=INT // this is fine
    ','
    y=id  // avoid: y might not be set if an exception occurs while parsing `id`
    ')';
```